# Proof of Tensor Product as Maps to a Field

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Maybe it's just convenient, but is there a proof that:

$V^\ast\otimes V^\ast:V\times V\to\mathbb{F}$

when only the universal property of the tensor product is assumed to hold? I've asked a similar question recently, but am looking here specifically for a *proof*.

Comment: For future reference, why was this down voted? I was hoping a proof would help me understand the generality of the tensor product.

Comment: What do you mean by $V^*\otimes V^*$ here? Are you interpreting the tensor product of the duals as a map from $V\times V$ to $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: The expression $V^*\otimes V^*:V\times V\to \Bbb F$ does not even compile in my head. I would understand that you're looking for a proof that $V^*\otimes V^*$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Lin}_2(V,\Bbb F)$. If this is the case, you should really write your question properly (not always will someone be able to guess what the question is, before answering it).

Comment: Anyway, check that given $f,g\in V^*$, the map $\varphi_{f,g}:V\times V\to \Bbb F$ is bilinear, and that $\varphi:V^*\times V^* \to {\rm Lin}_2 (V,\Bbb F)$ is also bilinear. Then there is $\Phi:V^*\otimes V^*\to  {\rm Lin}_2 (V,\Bbb F)$ satisfying $\Phi(f\otimes g)=\varphi_{f,g}$ for all $f,g\in V^*$. This is the isomorphism.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $lin_2$, but now that you mention it that's what I'm trying to ask. I found it in a lecture series on youtube (XylyXylyX). I'm such a newbie it seemed to me like a true statement (he said it had linearity but didn't write it that way), but that's why I'm asking about it. Sorry!

Comment: The relation is $$V^*\otimes V=\{T:V\times V\to\Bbb F\ |\ \mbox{$T$ is a bilinear map}\}.$$ If $V$ is generated by, say $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ and $V^*$ generated by $\{\beta^1,...,\beta^n\}$ then with $\beta^ i(b_j)=\delta^i{}_j$ and $$T=T_{kl}\beta^k\otimes\beta^l,$$ is a bi-indexed linear combination.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn: I missed to write $V^*\otimes V^*$ above

Comment: admit my upvote 'cuz I feel your question and you confusion is genuine and the downvoters are unjust.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal: $V^*\otimes V^*$ is the  vector space generated by the tensor products $\beta^k\otimes\beta^l$ where the $\beta^s$ are the generators of $V^*$. These works as $\beta^k\otimes\beta^l(v,w)=v^kw^l$, because $$\beta^k(v^sb_s)=v^s\delta^k{}_s=v^k.$$